# web scraping... get everything withing a tag including other tags

Tags: html, web-scraping, lxml

I have the following tag

```
<div class="example">
    <p> text <a href="#"> link </a> text</p>
</div>
```

I want to get

```
<p> text <a href="#"> link </a> text</p>
```

so everything within the div with the class example.
I am using

```
from lxml import html
page = requests.get('X')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

description = tree.xpath('//div[@class="example"]/p//text()')
```

which gives me a list of paragraph tags which I then join together with

```
description = ' '.join('<p>{0}</p>'.format(paragraph) for paragraph in description)
```

but there must be a way to directly get the content within a div?
thanks
carl

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution... not pretty but it gives me what I want...

```
dummy = tree.xpath('//div[@class="example"]/div[2]/div/node()')   
description = ''
for paragraph in dummy:
    try:
        description += html.tostring(paragraph)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get all the nodes inside the tag:

```
h = """<div class="example">
<p> text <a href="#"> link </a> text</p>
<p> othertext <a href="#"> otherlink </a> text</p>
</div>"""

from lxml import html

x = html.fromstring(h)

print("".join(html.tostring(n) for n in x.xpath("//div[@class='example']/*")))
```

Output:

```
<p> text <a href="#"> link </a> text</p>
<p> othertext <a href="#"> otherlink </a> text</p>
```

Or use `.iterchildren`:

```
"".join(html.tostring(n) for n in x.xpath("//div[@class='example']")[0].iterchildren())
```

There is no need for any try/except either.